# can magento add store with different subdomain?

Tags: magento, magento2

it's my first time to use magento
my main domain for exmple domain .com with centos OS
my magento on store.domain .com with Ubuntu 16
can i use the same Ubuntu  server for another store with sub domain store2.domain .com ?
P.S my main domain domain .com uses wordpress Cms
thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You Can add store with different subdomain. Follow below steps:

1. Go to admin then select tab System->manage stores
2. Click create store view and complete the form and save store view

Change the Base URL for each Store view

1.Go to admin then select tab System->configuration

2.On the left side of the page General under that select web but before that you have to change the Current Configuration Scope to your store view name

3.Edit the base url to you subdomain(eg: http://en.yourdomain.com)

4.click save config.

Change `.htaccess` for redirecting to store view if you call the subdomain

1.Your .htaccess file is at the root folder of magento.

2.Search for "RewriteEngine on" word  in .htaccess file and write the code below it

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en.yourdomain.com
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:english]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fr. yourdomain .com
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:french]
```

then save the .htaccess file and try to clear all cache and browsing history from your browser as well as from magento.